# Como le hago para que en vez de saber el % de filas sea el de columnas?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Xnorux
      {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       float array []=new float [3];
       int SFil;
       int tabla[][] = {
                    { 95, 45, 37, 70, 85 },
                    { -4, 10, 92, 49, 48 },
                    { 2, 30, 51, 100, -9 }
       };
       for(int i = 0; i<tabla.length; i++)
       {
           SFil=0;

           for(int j = 0; j<tabla[i].length; j++)
           {
               if (tabla[i][j]%2!=0)
               {
                   SFil++;
               }
           }
           array[i]=(100*SFil)/tabla[i].length;
           System.out.println("\nLa fila "+i+" tiene "+SFil+" números impares ("+array[i]+"%)");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu código tienes dos bucles anidados, el primero usa `i` para iterar sobre las filas y el segundo usa `j` para iterar sobre las columnas.

Si los intercambias, puedes recorrer las columnas con `i`, resultando algo como:

```
int numFilas = tabla.length;
int numColumnas = tabla[0].length;
double array [] = new double [numColumnas];
for(int i = 0; i < numColumnas; i++) {
    SFil=0;

    for(int j = 0; j < numFilas; j++) {
        if (tabla[j][i]%2 != 0) {
               SFil++;
        }
    }
    array[i] = (100*SFil) / numColumnas;
    System.out.println("\nLa columna "+i+" tiene "+SFil+" números impares ("+array[i]+"%)");
    }
```